# Best way to compare VARCHAR2 with CHAR

Tags: oracle, char, comparison, varchar2

I'm searching for the best (and fastest) way to compare `VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)` with `CHAR(12 BYTE)`.

There are two databases, first contains a table1 with CHAR column (underline means space characters to fill CHAR length)

```
ID  VALUE
1   123-45___
2   123-456__
3   123-457__
```

second database (table2) contains VARCHAR2 without white space.

```
ID  VALUE
4   123-45
5   123-456
6   123-457
```

So, I want something like this

```
SELECT table1.ID FROM table1 WHERE table1.VALUE = '123-45'
```

Comment: Is the `value` column indexed?

Comment: of course there is an index, the content is very different and have got 50000 rows

Comment: Why would you ever want to use `char`? It has absolutely no advantage over `varchar` but several sever disadvantages

Comment: You are right, but this wasn't my question because I can't change it. First database is from an external third party.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the `table1.value` column is indexed, you don't want to manipulate that for the comparison as that would prevent the index being used. So you'll need to modify the value you're looking up:

```
SELECT table1.ID FROM table1 WHERE table1.VALUE = RPAD('123-45', 12)
```

Oracle will do that implicitly with the query you showed though, and will still use the index. And the same if you're joining the tables, but whether you pad or trim during the join depends on which table is the driver:

```
SELECT table1.ID, table2.ID
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table2.value = RTRIM(table1.value)
WHERE table1.VALUE = RPAD('123-45', 12)
```

Or:

```
SELECT table1.ID
FROM table2
JOIN table1 ON table1.value = RPAD(table2.value, 12)
```