# ORACLE SUBQUERY NOT WORKING IN (IN CONDITION)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need help

i have records 123,456,789 in rows when i am execute like

this one is working

```
select * from table1 where num1 in('123','456')
```

but when i am execute

```
select * from table1 where num1 in(select value from table2)
```

no resultset found - why?

Comment: Most likely you have records where `value` is **NULL**

Comment: value is 123,456

Comment: What RS returned by `select value from table2`?

Comment: select value from table2     and resultset is => 123,456

Answer (score 0):

Check the DataType varchare2 or Number

try

```
select * from table1 where num1 in(select to_char(value) from table2)
```

Comment: did you tried this :  select * from table1 where to_number(num1) in(select value from table2)

Comment: ---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
ORA-01722: invalid number

---------------------------
OK   Lookup Oracle Documentation ...   Copy runtime exception log   
---------------------------

Comment: That means  some data in your column is not a number  (could be null )

Comment: select value from table2 i got resultset 123,456

Comment: No the problem is from  table1 coulmn   num1

Comment: select * from table1 where num1 in('123','456') is working but select * from table1 where num1 in(select value from table2) not working

Comment: num1 datatype is char(4) and value datatype is varchar2(255)

Comment: It is datatype issue : user RPAD function also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083054/best-way-to-compare-varchar2-with-char

Comment: select * from table1 where num1 in RPAD((select value from table2))  or select * from table1 where num1 in(select RPAD(value) from table2)  not working

Comment: ---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
ORA-00938: not enough arguments for function

---------------------------
OK   Lookup Oracle Documentation ...   Copy runtime exception log   
---------------------------

Comment: select * from table1 where rpad(num1,12) in(select value from table2)  not working

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, an important thing to remember: **Do not** store numbers in character datatypes. Use `NUMBER` or `INTEGER`. Secondly, always prefer `VARCHAR2` datatype over `CHAR` if you wish to store characters > 1.

You said in one of your comments that `num1` column is of type `char(4)`. The problem with `CHAR` datatype is that If your string is 3 characters wide, it stores the record by adding extra 1 space character to make it 4 characters. `VARCHAR2` only stores as many characters as you pass while inserting/updating and are not blank padded.

To verify that you may run `select length(any_char_col) from t;`

Coming to your problem, the `IN` condition is never satisfied because what's actually being compared is

`WHERE 'abc ' = 'abc'` - Note the extra space in left side operator.

To fix this, one good option is to pad the right side expression with as many spaces as required to do the right comparison.The function  `RPAD( string1, padded_length [, pad_string] )` could be used for this purpose.So, your query should look something like this.

**`select * from table1 where num1  IN (select rpad(value,4) from table2);`**

This will likely utilise an index on the column `num1` if it exists.

The other one is to use `RTRIM` on LHS, which is only useful if there's a function based index on `RTRIM(num1)`

**`select * from table1 where RTRIM(num1) in(select value from table2);`**

So, the takeaway from all these examples is always use `NUMBER`  types to store numbers and prefer `VARCHAR2` over `CHAR` for strings.

See [**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7d99c0aa962c2b14dc67d4264184f96a) to fully understand what's happening.

**EDIT** : It seems You are storing comma separated numbers.You could do something like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM table2 t2
     WHERE ',' ||t2.value|| ',' LIKE '%,' || rtrim(t1.num1) || ',%'
);
```

See [**Demo2**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f815c69ad08877dbbf0aed5ac75089a2)

Storing comma separated values are bound to cause problems, better change it.

Comment: i want this output =>  
select * from table1 where num1 in('123','456')


select * from table1 where num1 in(select value from table2)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=145da75c6ab77a2cffde4ad4d468373c     check this not working

Comment: @ShahHarsh : you made a mistake while inserting `INSERT INTO table2 (value) VALUES (456,123);` There should be two separate inserts for 123 and 456

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5858d8619543b3308fb59da7024f82b0    now whats my mistake

Comment: @ShahHarsh: You can't insert 2 values in a single statement like that. Do you see the message `ORA-00913: too many values` in your dbfiddle link?

Comment: @ShahHarsh : Ah, you didn't explain it correctly in your question. See edits of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Storing comma separated values could be the cause of problem.
You can try using regexp_substr to split comma.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution using string array

```
SELECT T.* FROM TABLE1 T,
(SELECT TRIM(VALUE)AS VAL FROM TABLE2)TABLE2
WHERE
TRIM(NUM1) IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(FUNC_GETSTRING_ARRAY(TABLE2.VAL)))
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you first,

> You have stored values in `table2` which `is comma seperated`.

So, **how could you** match your data with `table1` and `table2`. 
*Its not Possible*. 
**That's why you did not get any values in result set**.